# Mapping interface to struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

Is it possible somehow in gorm to pass an interface that is a data model (structure) to the `Find` method. Example:

```
 func MyFunc (results interface {}) error {
     // anything actions
     err: = c.db.Raw (query, valuesWhere ...). Find (& results) .Error
     // anything actions
 }
```

Call:

```
 var p [] * Project
 MyFunc (p)
```

### The document you expected this should be explained

Docs, you can find [here](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html) or [here](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html).

### Expected answer

I want to get answer yes or no. If you say yes, please write the code with example. I cannot implement it by myself.

Comment: Second example [here](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Inline-Condition).

Comment: Regarding your comment—`Find` accepts `interface{}` and internally performs type-switching on the dynamic type of the concrete value kept in the interface value passed to it (no, really, you could read the source code), so that example explains how to pass `struct` types to `Find`, and more. In the example in your question you appear to pass a pointer to a value of type `interface{}` (that `&results` bit); I think `Find` has no idea how to handle this.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is this:

```
 func MyFunc (results interface{}) error {
     // anything actions
     err: = c.db.Raw(query, valuesWhere ...).Find(results).Error
     // anything actions
 }
```

Call:

```
 var p []Project
 MyFunc (&p)
```

[Answer](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4163) at github.